# Making a css grid equal height rows independently

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a css grid with equal height rows (it's a product grid). Right now all rows are equal height, but they should be equal height independently, meaning not all rows should be same height, just each row should be the height of the largest column on that specific row.

Right now my css is like this:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
grid-column-gap: 0;
grid-row-gap: 0;
display: grid;
```

But how can i make each row adjust their height based on the biggest column in any given row.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Remove the 1fr from the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;` or set `auto`(`grid-auto-rows: auto;`)

check example:-
https://codepen.io/rvtech/pen/qBaGEoW